# textview with more than 32767 characters causes the application to crash

Tags: android, textview

The textview that doesn't display is a help text with about 62000 characters. I get user failures on the pixel 2 with api 26 and api 27. The error message from the play store is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2778)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2856)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1589)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6494)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:438)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I've been able to duplicate it with an emulated pixel 2 using api 26 but using api 27 is ok. I've removed all extraneous code to simplify the problem and found that a textview with one more character than 32767, ie 32768 characters will crash the app when I access help.java for my help screen. I've included all relevent code but not the full string. The string I used is only CRLF, numbers, and alpha characters. I can't figure out the problem with the code.

The logcat is:

```
05-15 19:45:26.458 4340-4340/steve.diabetescarbcounter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: steve.diabetescarbcounter, PID: 4340
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{steve.diabetescarbcounter/steve.diabetescarbcounter.Help}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:418)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2654)
        at steve.diabetescarbcounter.Help.onCreate(Help.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
        at android.content.res.StringBlock.nativeGetString(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:82)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.getPooledStringForCookie(AssetManager.java:332)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.loadStringValueAt(TypedArray.java:1272)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getText(TypedArray.java:175)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1142)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:818)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:814)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:418) 
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2654) 
        at steve.diabetescarbcounter.Help.onCreate(Help.java:22) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
05-15 19:45:27.620 1407-1407/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 109 ms
05-15 19:45:27.667 1655-1669/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
05-15 19:45:27.899 1409-1409/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 118 ms
05-15 19:45:28.342 2442-2525/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
05-15 19:45:29.338 2288-3690/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/ctxmgr: [ProducerStatusImpl]updateStateForNewContextData: inactive, contextName=7
05-15 19:45:29.371 1655-1769/system_process E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
05-15 19:45:29.605 2288-2288/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/BeaconBle: Scan couldn't start for Places
05-15 19:45:32.302 1655-1673/system_process E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
05-15 19:45:33.522 2442-2525/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
05-15 19:45:36.785 1655-1669/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
05-15 19:45:42.787 1655-1769/system_process E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
```

The java code is:

```
package steve.diabetescarbcounter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Help extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.help);
    }
}
```

The xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id = "@+id/helplinear1"
    style="@style/etool_linearlayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <TableLayout
        android:id = "@+id/helptablelayout1"
        style="@style/etool_tablelayout"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        >
        <TableRow
            android:id = "@+id/helptablerow1"
            style="@style/etool_tablerow"
            >
       </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:id = "@+id/scroll_view_help"
        style="@style/etool_scrollview"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id = "@+id/helplinear2"
            style="@style/etool_linearlayout"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/helpText"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/helpcrash"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The string helpcrash is just a random string of 32768 characters not shown:

```
<string name="helpcrash">then 32768 characters </string>
```

The manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="steve.diabetescarbcounter"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <!-- If you change the version to 23 or higher then you will have to implement marshmallow permissions model -->
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/noTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RecentActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/noTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/noTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ItemActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/noTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Nutrients"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/noTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/noTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Help"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/noTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
     </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: From the stack trace, that appears to be a limitation on the length of a string resource.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your TextView

```
android:maxLength="60000"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I tried android:maxLength="60000" in the TextView to no avail. I searched in the path to see if it gets set anywhere else and didn't find any occurrence. Since the characters are 16 bits, 32767 * 2 + 1 is the  max value for a 16 bit int. I expected that a java string could be up to 2^31-1 characters so this should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

After trying the android:maxLength="60000" in the xml with no fix, I tried to programmatically add the large string in the Java code like this:

```
helpText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helpText);
String helpstring = getString(R.string.help1);  
helpText.setText(Html.fromHtml(helpstring));
```

This failed again when the string resource help1 was more than 32767 characters. My conclusion was that getting the string from the string resource was limited to less than or equal 32767 characters.

I split the string resource into three strings and then concatenated them with this code:

```
helpText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helpText);
String helpstring = getString(R.string.help1) + getString(R.string.help2) + getString(R.string.help3);
helpText.setText(Html.fromHtml(helpstring));
```

This worked just fine where each string was about 20,000 characters. Unfortunately getString strips all html formatting from the strings. I had to go through all the strings and replace \n with %lt;br> and then overall replace < with %lt; to "hide" the html formatting from getString and from this comment as well. In the setText I had to restore the html formatting with Html.fromHtml().

In conclusion, the TextView can handle large strings as expected but the process of getting the string from the string resource is more difficult than expected. This worked for me since the string resource is essentially fixed in size and I could split it into several pieces.